# Code slows down on Unhide rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have this procedure that loops over worksheets to perform some tasks.
On each worksheets it has to chceck if any rows/columns are hidden and if there is autofilter mode is on. If yes, it has to unhide them and turn off autofilter. I have something like this in my code:

```
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData 
Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False 
Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

I've noticed that procedure slows down on the line `Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False`. It takes like 1-2 sec. so with few worksheets it's not a big problem but with many worksheets it affects speed of the macro.

Do You khnow maybe better way to do this stuff?

Comment: Doesn'y ShowAllData  unhide hidden rows?

Comment: What are the chances you will have hidden rows or columns outside of the UsedRange and even if you did, why bother unhiding them?

Comment: Changing the worksheet in any way will slow down code, and should be avoided as much as possible.  Perhaps don't hide/unhide at all; maybe put that data on a separate sheet.

Comment: The more formulas are in rows to hide / unhide, the slower it gets. Looking at how you operate on active sheet's columns and rows, perhaps you can eliminate activating worksheet / setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Comment: I have to unhide all rows and columns because I read the values from the specific range to array and perform calculations in it. Unfortunetley I am not the owner of these files. People in my department store data in it, and I am writing tools to handle this data. Unfortunately, there are quite big chances that some of the rows/columns might be hidden. ShowAllData unhides rows, but not columns. I've added these three lines to be sure that all of the data are visible during reading them to an array. I of course added lines that improve speed like turniong off screen updating, disabled events,..